# Showing certain page without redirection

Tags: pages, page-template

I need to get any url that starts with "booking" to lead to certain post without redirection.

That means all of these URL would lead to post Booking, but the URL would stay the way it is:

```
example.com/booking
example.com/booking/rooms
example.com/booking/rooms/show/kabana-3
```

This is because in the page template of the post Booking I have a PHP script that needs full URL.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['wp_rewrite']`, the [T5 Rewrite Plugin](https://github.com/toscho/t5-rewrite/), [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and the [Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API). Please show us some code.

Comment: The problem is that example.com/booking/rooms gives 404 error and I would like it to show example.com/booking.

Comment: Hence I mentioned all those links in my last comment. Showing your research effort and some code is a prerequisite for this site. A task alone is no question. :)

Comment: I can't think of any relevant code that would enhance clarity of my question. I've looked at all of the plugins you wrote above, thank you for those. However, I find they are able only to construct URL from post's information and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Those plugins help you solving the question with _inspecting_ what happens. Having _some_ knowledge about your problem, showing your research and a will to learn and solve the problem is a _prerequisite_ to asking a question on this network site. Therefore I linked you those plugins so you can walk in and enhance your question with details, do some try and error to solve it, etc.